# Filter one DataFrame by another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`, with the same columns and where the indices of `df2` is a subset of the indices in `df1`.

I want to output a DataFrames with the indices from `df1`, but with all cells set to 0, except cells having the value 1 in `df2` *(i.e. the values in `df1` do not actually matter)*.

---

Here is an example:

First DataFrame `df1`:

```
                  C1  C2  C3  C4
               A   0   0   0   0
               B   0   0   0   0
               C   0   0   0   0
               D   0   0   0   0
               E   1   1   1   1
               F   1   1   1   1
```

Second DataFrame `df2`:

```
                  C1  C2  C3  C4
               B   1   1   1   1
               C   1   1   1   1
               D   1   1   1   1
```

Expected output:

```
                  C1  C2  C3  C4
               A   0   0   0   0
               B   1   1   1   1
               C   1   1   1   1
               D   1   1   1   1
               E   0   0   0   0
               F   0   0   0   0
```

---

Here is code to generate the the example data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'C1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        'C2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        'C3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        'C4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    },
    index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'C1': [1, 1, 1],
        'C2': [1, 1, 1],
        'C3': [1, 1, 1],
        'C4': [1, 1, 1],
    },
    index=['B', 'C', 'D'],
)

expected_output = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'C1': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        'C2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        'C3': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        'C4': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    },
    index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
)
```

---

The following can be assumed:

```py
assert all(df1.columns == df2.columns)
assert len(set(df2.index) - set(df1.index)) == 0
assert {0, 1} - set(df1.values.ravel()) == set()
assert {0, 1} - set(df2.values.ravel()) == set()
```

Comment: Why do you expect `E` and `F` to have `0` in them when they have `1` in the original dataframe?

Comment: @Nick, I expect just second data frame values should be 1 all other values should be 0.I want to filter the first datafarme based on second dataframe, only want to keep the second dataframe values here non zero, want to keep all other values 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set all the values in `df1` to `0`, then [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with the values from `df2`:

```py
df1[:] = 0
df1.update(df2)
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4
A   0   0   0   0
B   1   1   1   1
C   1   1   1   1
D   1   1   1   1
E   0   0   0   0
F   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can construct `df2` to `df1` structure

```py
out = df2.reindex_like(df1).fillna(0)
```

```
print(out)

    C1   C2   C3   C4
A  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
E  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
F  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```